# "Generating a random DFA with uniform distribution" - Where can I ask this kind of question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, algorithm, computer-science-se

I asked this [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525643/what-is-the-algorithm-for-generating-a-random-deterministic-finite-automata).  It appears building a random DFA, selected with uniform distribution, is more difficult than it seems.

Should I be asking this somewhere else, or have I come to the right place?

Comment: It is not clear to me that you have defined what you mean by *"uniform distribution"*.

Comment: The set of events is the set of all DFA with the 4 properties I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I merged both of your accounts together.  Second, StackOverflow isn't the appropriate place for questions about StackOverflow, [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is.  Third, if you had taken the time (I say this because of the previous two points) you may have learned that there is a StackExchange site that focuses on [**research-level** theoretical computer science questions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), which you might have found is a better target for your question.

Comment: The FAQ for cstheory.SE says it's for "research-level questions in theoretical computer science". This question doesn't sound research-level nor theoretical to me. I'm not qualified to judge, but my guess is that it's off-topic there.

Comment: @Gabe idk, I think that most of the audience there probably understands what he's asking for more than the chaps on SO. That said, it wouldn't hurt to ask on meta.TCS.se first and see what they have to say, if it's valid for the site.

Answer (score 2):

*(Since that meta post, you've had an answer. 24 hours for an answer to a relatively difficult question isn't anything to be worried about. I'll just respond to the general issue.)*

It sounds like you're looking for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). This didn't exist back then but does now.

There's also a [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), for [research-level](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq]) questions only. If you've done a serious search of the scientific literature and found nothing, you can ask experts if they know of results on that topic.